# Flask templates : Linking html pages

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to Flask. I have the index1.html as my home page. I have added a navigation bar with links to other html pages. How do I go about it?

```
nav>
  <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" onclick="$('nav ul').toggle()">☰MENU</button>
<ul>

<li class="active"><a href="index1.html" class="nav_tab" id="_a">Overview</a></li>  
<li><a href="search.html" class="nav_tab" id="_b">Search</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

The html pages are in the template folder. The 'overview' link should point at the home page (index1.html) while 'search' should go to the search.html page. How can I achieve this in flask ? 
My routes.py looks like this:

```
from flask import render_template
from tomvar import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index1.html')
```

Comment: Use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#url-building)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those HTML pages that are in your templates folder must be behind some route in your routes.py, so you should just defined the routes in your HTML href tag, somewhat like this. Clicking example will take you to `/search` behind which `search.html` page will open up for you.

```
<li class="active"><a href="/search">Example</a></li>
```

> Second Option

Or there is another solution for this, you can use url_for generates urls to routes defined in your application.

routes.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/index2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index_func():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do stuff when the form is submitted
        # redirect to end the POST handling
        # the redirect can be to the same route or somewhere else
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    # show the form, it wasn't submitted
    return render_template('index2.html')
```

templates/index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
   <p><a href="{{ url_for('index_func') }}">Check out</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```